# Getting all data in a Firebase column

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created JSON database tree and I can read specific values with these codes. I can see on table view "Albert Einstein"

```
ref.child("Personel").child("Name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let item = snapshot.value as? String{

                self.myList.append(item)
                self.LessonsTableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
```

[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/JlNEbj.png]

But, I want to see which categories under Personal column? Like this,

[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/9dApPO.png]

Is there any way to get or learn which columns are under "Personal"

Table view output must be -> Age, Name, Photo

Comment: A few things: There are no columns in Firebase, only parents and children which correspond to keys and values. You are asking which *children keys exist within a parent node*. (the keys in your example are Age, Name and Photo). You may want to update your question so it's a bit more clear. It's also a good question. In the future include your Firebase structure as text please, no images. That way we don't have to retype it if it's used in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the snapshot, get it's children and then those childrens keys

Say you have a users node with a user

```
users
  user_0
    fav_game: "WoW"
    name: "Leroy"
```

then to get the keys of name: and fav_game:

```
let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child("user_0")
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let key = snap.key
        print(key)
    }
})
```

prints

```
fav_game
name
```

An important note is

```
for child in snapshot.children
```

because that will keep the data (keys in this case) in order. If the snapshot is dumped into a dictionary it looses order.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through `snapshot.value` you should be able to get the `key`s from the database.

In JavaScript it would be something like:

```
ref.child("Personel").child("Name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let item = snapshot.value as? String{

        self.myList.append(item)
        self.LessonsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    var vals = snapshot.val();
    for(var property in vals) {
      console.log(property); // property has those values in it
    }

})
```

Comment: This code appends the values to an array - the OP wants the KEYS in the snapshot, not the values.

Comment: It does return the KEYS

Comment: How? Snapshot.value returns a *value* contained in the snapshot, not the key. In this answer, that value is then appended to the myList array. However, please note your ref in your answer is using the 'Name' key and the OP doesn't know the key so that won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
ref.child("Personel").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
    self.myList.append(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Age").value)
    self.myList.append(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value)
    self.myList.append(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Photo").value)
    self.LessonsTableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: This only works if the keys are known - he wants to get the actual keys, not the values ;-)

Comment: Ah... that would require a loop. I didn't feel like looking up the incantation required for the cast. But I see you did that in your answer already. :-D